# PHPMailer not sending, but no errors

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I created a php application at dan.creativeloafing.com. This just takes form data and builds an html page with it, then emails the contents of that page to dan@creativeloafing.com. A couple days ago, it stopped working. I have been trying to figure this out ever since. I was using the mail() php function and have switched it over to the PHPMailer Library. This is supposedly sending the emails and I get confirmation, but nobody ever recieves the email and I get no bounceback or any errors. This is the jist of the code:

```
//PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';     // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                            // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Username = 'dan@omgsurvey.com';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*******';                         // SMTP password

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->From = 'dan@omgsurvey.com';
$mail->FromName = 'DAN Application';
$mail->addAddress('dan@creativeloafing.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo($repEmail);
$mail->addCC('david.miller@creativeloafing.com');

$mail->isHTML(true); 

$mail->Subject = "New DAN Request: ".$campaignName;
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('./tmp/DAN_REQUEST_'.$specialString.$randomNumber.'.html'));

if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo '<br />Proposal could not be sent.<br />';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      exit;
} else {
  echo 'Proposal has been sent';
}
```

The script always reaches 'Proposal has been sent.' too. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Posting your mail password here is a bad idea unless it's a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

So what was happening here is that godaddy was blocking emails that included my domain name in them. I am not sure if this was a spam issue, but they are currently looking into it. I have gotten the emails to send using a simple mail() function and by removing any references to omgsurvey.com in the email. Silly, this mail was only ever sent to two email addresses!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
```

supposed to be:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try...catch and PHPMailer(true); https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/exceptions.phps

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
//Passing true to the constructor enables the use of exceptions for error handling
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

try {

mail->isSMTP();                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';     // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 25; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                            // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Username = 'dan@omgsurvey.com';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*******';                          // SMTP password

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->From = 'dan@omgsurvey.com';
$mail->FromName = 'DAN Application';
$mail->addAddress('dan@creativeloafing.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo($repEmail);
$mail->addCC('david.miller@creativeloafing.com');

$mail->isHTML(true); 

$mail->Subject = "New DAN Request: ".$campaignName;
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('./tmp/DAN_REQUEST_'.$specialString.$randomNumber.'.html'));

$mail->send();
echo 'Proposal has been sent';

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still echoes 'Proposal has been sent'. Would this mean that problem is not on my end, but with the host(godaddy)?

Comment: it's possible, try change with another SMTP server

Answer (score -1):

Thinking send() should be Send()

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
```

Comment: Please describe your solution and how it fixes the problem at hand. This helps future visitors to this question understand your solution.